# How do I make elements horizontally scrollable on mobile and not just resize?

Tags: css, mobile, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

Here is my HTML that I am trying to style:

```
<div id="cards-text-wrap">
  <h1 class="text">Some text here</h1>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the "scrollable card" divs actually scrollable (sideways). Right now they are only being resized to fit on the same line, which means it isn't overflowing on the Y-axis, which is good. But it isn't overflowing on the x-axis, which is what I want.

I tried to use a bunch of different methods, all of which resulted in the same wrong result. In this example I used overflow-x to try to make it overflow out of the viewport, but it is still not doing that.

And the css looks like this:

```
 #cards-text-wrap {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 230px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .text {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .scrollable-card {
    width: 180px;
    height: 210px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 26px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    resize: none;
  }

  .card-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 210px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

The result I am getting from this is the outermost div looks fine and the text looks fine, but the elements are squished to roughly 40 pixels, instead of their set width of 180px. It is also not overflowing at all on the x-axis.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
 #cards-text-wrap {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 230px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .text {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .scrollable-card {
    min-width: 180px;
    height: 210px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 26px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .card-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 210px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<body>  
 <div id="cards-text-wrap">
  <h1 class="text">Some text here</h1>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
    <div class="scrollable-card"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```